# Why Isn't My Data Being Shown?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables in my database:

Minutes: `minute_id, subject, next_subject, approval, meeting_id`

Agendas: `agenda_id, subject, duration, approval, reason, meeting_id`

I am using the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Agendas INNER JOIN Minutes ON Minutes.meeting_id = Agendas.meeting_id WHERE Agendas.Approval = 'disapproved'")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo 'You Have No New Messages';
} else {

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Title: '. $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Approved?: '. $info['approval']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Reason: '. $info['reason']."</td>";
        echo "<hr>";

    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I am not getting the desired data to be shown as I am only been presented with the message 'You Have No New Messages' when in the agendas table, there is a row which has a field disapproved!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running the query from mysql command line to see if any rows were returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an INNER JOIN... make sure there is also an associated row in the minutes table, or else there will be no data to return, even if there is an entry in Agendas.

Comment: Related to this: check also that entries in agenda that have minutes also have the approval clause you've mentioned.